# Eliminate the second child of a ul

Tags: wordpress, css

I don't know why but in my shop page the products are repeated. It's a problem of incompatibility between the filter plugin and the theme I'm using. For a quick solution I'd like to use custom css code and hide the second `<ul class="products">`. Please take a look at my shop: https://www.editorialufv.es/catalogo/

I've tried adding the following css custom code but nothing changes. Why?

```
ul.products:nth-child(2){
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ul.products:nth-child(6)`

Honestly I can't tell you why that works as I have trouble with the `nth-*` selectors myself but it does work. If anyone else can shed some light on why it is the 6th child that would be great!

Also, just a tip. If you open the browser dev tools and right click on an element in the inspector there you will see an option to "copy selector". That can be really useful for cases like this.

Comment: That's great and it works perfectly. Now I have another problem. How can I hide all the ul(s) that appear as soon as you filter a product? Take a try on my shop: https://www.editorialufv.es/catalogo/ Is there a way to hide the second ul on every page which URL starts with https://www.editorialufv.es/catalogo/ ?

Comment: Honestly, at that point you probably just want to address the actual problem instead of trying to just hide the extra elements with CSS. There are two approaches to hide things as I'm sure you know, one is a specific rule and the other is a more general rule. The problem with the former is you will need to hunt down and address each occurrence; the problem with the latter is, there are other `ul` elements on the page that you will not want hidden like the menu. If I were you I'd just try and figure out why there are two showing in the first place and correct it.

Comment: Also if this answer helped, please mark it as correct so others with similar issues will know. :)

Comment: Sure, you're right but I have no idea why there are two results showing! Do you have any idea?

Comment: This plugin is adding the top part and the theme is adding the bottom? How familiar are you with editing WP templates and PHP? I have a feeling the part you want removed is automatically added via the page template in use. You can use a plugin like [What The File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) to figure out what template file is being used then override it in a child theme with the code that adds the second list removed.

Comment: I'm not so good on editing WP templates and PHP. The plugin What The file tells me that the templates files in use on my shop page are the header-nav.php and the header-title.php Moreover there's the woocommerce.php file and maybe here is the solution. Here the file, do you find anything that could fix my problem? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ly55kgkcmhuxa1o/woocommerce.docx?dl=0

Comment: I think the file would be something with "archive" in the name but woocommerce.php may be the file responsible too. This seems to be out of scope of the original question though. I recommend checking out the WP [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) docs, trying to figure out what file is being used, then editing it as needed. If you run into problems editing it then come back here and post a new question.

Comment: Actually I just saw the dropbox link. Yes that looks like the file that's doing it. See towards the bottom of the file there is a `<div class"kode-item woocommerce-content-item">` tag? Then on the site that same tag is used and the part that you don't want shown is inside it. Try changing `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?> ` to `<?php //woocommerce_content(); ?> ` and that should fix it (it may have unintended effects on other pages though.)

Comment: Unfortunately this change doesn't fix the problem. As you can see, now all the links of the books are empty. Still looking for the solution. What a mistery!

Comment: I suggest you open a new question on the [WP stack stackexchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Post the code from that file and say you tried commenting out the `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` but it broke everything. This is too much for the comment section here.

Comment: Done. Looking for a solution with a custom shop page. Take a look: wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289233/layout-shop-page-resize-images-and-columns